# Is it possible to return from the *calling* method using IL?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, il

There's an annoying quirk in the way `Response.Redirect` works: you almost always want to terminate excecution right away and jump to the new page:

```
If ThisIsTheWrongPage Then
    Response.Redirect(sUrl, False)
End If

'this code should not execute
DoSomethingWithThisPage
```

But `Response.Redirect` doesn't end execution, it just keeps on going and executes the subsequent lines of code. This is causing a lot of havoc in a legacy app I'm maintaining. So you have to do this:

```
If ThisIsTheWrongPage Then
    Response.Redirect(sUrl, False)
    Return
End If
```

What I would like to do is implement a method like this:

```
Sub RedirectToUrl(sUrl As String)
  'redirect to the specified url
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(sUrl, False)

  'return from the CALLING method
End Sub
```

And then I could write this:

```
If ThisIsTheWrongPage Then
    RedirectToUrl(sUrl)
End If
```

And not have to worry about the missing Return statement. I know it's not hard to write that return statement, but there are about 1,000 of these in the code, and new ones being added, and I want a method that the developer can call and not have to be careful about that `Return` statement. It's a bug just waiting to happen.

I know there's no way to do this in traditional .NET code, but I was wondering if it could be implemented in IL, to pop the stack twice and jump to the calling method's return location.

Comment: No, IL is a safe language. The kind of thing you're trying to do is inherently unsafe (obviously, otherwise why wouldn't the developers of .NET already provide a method that really "kills" the rest of the request?)

Comment: I think it would require great caution, certainly, but I don't see why it couldn't be done reliably.

Comment: The rules are simple - the only thing in a method that's allowed to interrupt execution of its parents is an exception. And this is not what you should use exceptions for. The fact is, you have no idea what happens when IL is being converted to e.g. x86. For example, the simple method you've just written would most likely simply be inlined. So instead of two `pop`s getting you out of two methods, they would get you out of *three* methods. An IL method must undergo validation in isolation - how can you validate a method that *depends* on what's on top of it?

Comment: Hmm, you make a good point. I guess it would be more dangerous than I thought.

Answer (score 2):

The only way a method can change the return point of the method that invoked it is to throw an exception. Considering the way many web apps are written with exception handlers to keep pages from returning 500 errors to the user, it could be difficult to provide your desired behavior by throwing an exception.

One problem with instructing a caller to return is there would be no way to specify the return value of that method. Exceptions work around this by propagating the exception itself up the stack until a handler is found.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. You'd be breaking invariants of the calling method. It would be unpredictable what happens when you call a method that you didn't write.

`Redirect` has a parameter that can be set to make it throw a `ThreadAbortException` on the current thread. This is made exactly for your use case. It effectively aborts execution of the page.

Comment: And the resulting `ThreadAbortException` is actually a killer in ASP.NET performance, so the answer really is "No, don't do this.".

Comment: @usr: Luann is right about performance, but even worse, it jumps to existing Catch blocks that do things, and in some cases those are **other redirects**. It's a bad design that I inherited and I'm just trying to clean up with a minimum of side effects.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank Even worse, in facts. Not only will it jump to existing catch blocks, the exception actually gets rethrown at the end of each of these catch blocks. Ouch.

Comment: @Luaan A rethrow statement `throw;` is not nearly as expensive as the original throw statement `throw ex;`.

Comment: @280Z28 Yeah, that's not what I meant - I meant that it will *execute* all the `catch` statements up to the root. You have no idea what that might do, like rolling back transactions etc.

Comment: @Luaan If you are cancelling the request for the purpose of a redirect, you would be doing all those operations anyway. Either that, or the operations would have already been committed and there is nothing to cancel/rollback.

Comment: Exception handling is usually a very rare thing in ASP.NET. Also, the whole runtime is made to withstand the TAE that Redirect raises. Performance is also not an absolute counter-point. You only need *enough* performance. I think the redirect by TAE technique isn't totally absurd. Better not use it, but you could.; Also, what you ask for simply does not exist.

Comment: Well, complicating this whole thing is that the original thing was designed with a `Response.Redirect(url)` pattern, and a `Try...Catch` block to catch the resulting TAE. So there are 1000 places that do this, and furthermore they catch **all** exceptions, not just the TAE, and some of those have other logic in them. So I really want a solution that doesn't involve exceptions, so I don't get tangled up in the existing Catch blocks.

Comment: Under these circumstances I give up.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this, it uses the [jmp opcode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.jmp%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),
maybe this fits your needs.

```
.assembly JumpTest{}
.module JumpTest.exe
.namespace Test{
.class public auto ansi JumpClass extends [mscorlib]System.Object {
    .method public static void Main() cil managed{
        .entrypoint 
        .maxstack 8

        ldstr "start"
        call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        ldstr ""
        call void Test.JumpClass::Page(string)
        ldstr "end"
        call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        ret
    }

    .method public static void Page(string sUrl) cil managed{
        ldc.i4.1 //always redirect in this test
        brfalse.s target

        jmp void Test.JumpClass::RedirectToUrl(string)

        target:
        ldstr "Page() stuff here"
        call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        ret
    }

    .method public static void RedirectToUrl(string sUrl) cil managed{
        ldstr "RedirectToUrl() stuff here"
        call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        ret
    }
}}
```